# Time for a procedure to run in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

How can I find the time it took to run a procedure in NetLogo?

Using 'ticks' defined in NetLogo is inaccurate for my purposes.

A vague idea would to subtract the system time at the start and end of
procedure if possible.

But I am unaware of any methods defined in NetLogo which would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charles' suggestion of the profiler extension is a great. The profiler extension is incredibly useful. However, it may be overkill for your situation.

Checkout [`reset-timer`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-timer) and [`timer`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#timer). `reset-timer` sets an internal timer to 0, and then `timer` reports the amount of time that has passed since `reset-timer` was called (in seconds). The resolution is on the order of milliseconds, but depends on the system.

To time a single procedure call, you'd do something like:

```
reset-timer
my-procedure
print timer
```

If you want to get a sense of the average time a procedure takes, you can simply put it in a `repeat` block:

```
reset-timer
repeat 1000 [ my-procedure ]
print timer
```