# Regarding Time scale issue in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am new user of netlogo. I have a system of reactions (converted to Ordinary Differential Equations), which can be solved using Matlab. I want to develop the same model in netlogo (for comparison with matlab results). I have the confusion regarding time/tick because netlogo uses "ticks" for increment in time, whereas Matlab uses time in seconds. How to convert my matlab sec to number of ticks? Can anyone help me in writing the code. The model is :

```
A + B ---> C (with rate constant k1 = 1e-6) 
2A+ C ---> D (with rate constant k2 = 3e-7)
A + E ---> F (with rate constant k3 = 2e-5)
```

Initial values are `A = B = C = 500`,  `D = E = F = 10`
Initial time `t=0` sec and final time `t=6` sec

Comment: re: ticks vs seconds, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571485/netlogo-1-tick-how-many-seconds

Comment: re: modeling chemical reactions, have you looked in Sample Models -> Chemistry & Physics -> Chemical Reactions? lots of chemical reaction models in there.

Answer (score 1):

I have a general comment first, NetLogo is intended for agent-based modelling. ABM has multiple entities with different characteristics interacting in some way. ABM is not really an appropriate methodology for solving ODEs. If your goal is to simply build your model in something other than Matlab for comparison rather than specifically requiring NetLogo, I can recommend Vensim as more appropriate. Having said that, you can build the model you want in NetLogo, it is just very awkward.

NetLogo handles time discretely rather than continuously. You can have any number of ticks per second (I would suggest 10 and then final time is 60 ticks). You will need to convert your equations into a discrete form, so your rates would be something like k1-discrete = k1 / 10. You may have precision problems with very small numbers.