# ticks and hours in NetLogo

Tags: time, netlogo

Is there some type of conversion for ticks to a unit of real time? I would like my program to simulate a 48 hour experiment. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of [NetLogo: 1 tick = how many seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571485/netlogo-1-tick-how-many-seconds)

Comment: I saw that post, but I didn't think it really answered my question. I know there is no actual conversion, but is there still a way to tell my simulation to rum for 48 hours? Would I use the "every" command?

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain better exactly what it is that you want to do? What does "tell my simulation to run for 48 hours" even mean, to you?

Answer (score 0):

How quickly do things change in your experiment? From system dynamics, a good rule of thumb is to have a discrete clock tick 4 times during the smallest interval of real time in which something meaningful happens in the modelled system. For example, if you would expect to see changes every minute, then you would have 4 ticks each minute (and your ABM rules about updating the system would be calculated on the basis of 15 seconds) and then run the simulation for 11,520 (=48x60x4) ticks.